# getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to connect to the Oracle database and ask how many methods are in the String class. I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

at the following line:

```
ResultSet res1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT (Distinct method_name) FROM all_java_method WHERE name LIKE 'String' Order BY method_name");
```

I don't have a ton of experience with SQL yet so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try substitute `(Distinct method_name)` with `Distinct method_name` and `'String'` with `'String%'` or `'%String%'`

Comment: Awesome! it works now. Thanks! What made the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute `(Distinct method_name)` with `Distinct method_name` because that is the correct syntax for the `SELECT`
Also, you need to substitute `'String'` with `'String%'` or `'%String%'` (depends on what exactly are you wanna fetch, I don't know java, so...), otherwise it is logicaly become equal to `name = 'String'`